# Why there is a green start shows up on document?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, web-part

my colleague uploaded five documents into the sharepoint in the earlier time. However, there is one of the documents appears a green start beside the document. Does anyone know what is that mean? And those five document all cannot open so no one can view on the contents, anyone what's going on with these document?

Comment: can you include the image, what you are seeing? it is may be new document or checkout or something else?

Comment: Sorry that I cannot upload any image cos it is a company sharepoint. There is no any logo or icon for the 5 documents except the first got the green start.

Answer (score 1):

A green star means the item is new. By default, the icon will show for 2 days. You can adjust this in SharePoint on-prem via:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://webAppUrl
$wa.DaysToShowNewIndicator = <numeric_value>
$wa.Update()
```